# 'https://librealsense.intel.com/Debian/apt-repo focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'

Tags: 20.04, package-management

I was trying to install [Reaslsense SDK](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/distribution_linux.md) and it did'nt went through, now I want to remove it as because of it I am getting an error while updating

```
 Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'https://librealsense.intel.com/Debian/apt-repo focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'
```

and upgrading

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dpkg : Breaks: libapt-pkg5.0 (< 1.7~b) but 1.2.35 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Are you mixing ARM and AMD system files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by using following steps:

1. Go to `sources.list` using `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`, remove the listed repository related to `realsense` and `librealsense`.
2. `sudo apt remove ubuntu-advantage-tools`
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt upgrade`